# SQL Stored Procedure - Search an array of strings in a field and display the count of occurrences

Tags: arrays, string, stored-procedures, sql-server-2000

In our case, we're restricted to SQL Server 2000.

Say we have a table "Articles" with a field "ArticleText". How do we search a string consisted of many words, and return the number of found occurrences.

An example of a search string: **John is a nice boy** (so it contains 5 words)

```
ID  ArticleText                         Result
1   John is going to learn              2
2   John is doing his homework nice-ly  3
3   John is a nice boy                  5
```

Up to now I've found a [split function](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/itai/archive/2009/02/01/t-sql-split-function.aspx) 
 for sql server 2000 to delimit the search string. Now I'm trying to iterate through the records and display the count of found words in one field, but I got stuck. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SQL Server 2000 solution**

New idea. Try splitting the search string first into 1 temp table. Then joining back to the articles using wild cards.

```
DECLARE @Search nvarchar(200); 
SET @Search = 'John is a nice boy'; 
IF NOT OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#S') IS NULL
DROP TABLE #S; 

SELECT * 
INTO #S 
FROM dbo.Split(@Search, ' '); 

SELECT a.ID, a.ArticleText, COUNT(*) as [Result] 
FROM #S as s 
JOIN Articles as a on a.ArticleText like s.Data + ' %' 
OR a.ArticleText like '% ' + s.Data + '%' 
GROUP BY a.ID, a.ArticleText
```

I tested this on SQL Server 2008 R2 with 2000 compatibility mode.

The 2 join conditions ensure that it matches the first word or any beginning of words (to get 'nice-' ). 
You should tweak this to your requirements and consider replace functions for the hyphen and other punctuation.

Comment: @Gazmend : The error "There is already an ..." is normal behaviour. You need to drop the table first. I have edited the answer above.

Answer (score 1):

**SQL Server 2008 solution**

You use cross apply, which passes each value from a table into the function and joins the result.

```
SELECT a.ID, a.ArticleText, COUNT(*) as [Result]
FROM Articles as a
CROSS APPLY dbo.Split(a.ArticleText,' ') as S
WHERE S.Data IN ('John','is','a','nice','boy')
GROUP BY a.ID, a.ArticleText
```

Interestingly, if you are just passing in the text as a single string, which is more likely when you replace the example text. You can use the Split function for that as well e.g. 'John is a nice boy' from a procedure parameter or local variable.

```
SELECT a.ID, a.ArticleText, COUNT(*) as [Result]
FROM Articles as a
CROSS APPLY dbo.Split(a.ArticleText,' ') as S
WHERE S.Data IN (SELECT Data FROM dbo.Split(@Search,' '))
GROUP BY a.ID, a.ArticleText
```

Comment: Thank you Rusell, but it won't work with sql server 2000. It gives the error:
Line 3: Incorrect syntax near 'APPLY'.

Comment: Yes this would only apply to 2005+. This was a limitation in 2000 and a workaround would likely involve dynamic sql or the dreaded cursor.   Have you considered a full-text search? This is when your detailed use case would benefit.

Answer (score 0):

Rusell, Thanks a lot man.

Now, I had a problem with the #S
**"There is already an object named '#S' in the database."**

and also with the:

```
SELECT * INTO @tblWords FROM dbo.Split(@Search, ' ');
```

But nevermind, i fixed it, so I'm sending the code that works in SQL 2000.

```
declare @Search varchar(100)
set @Search = 'John is a nice boy'

DECLARE @tblWords TABLE(IDArray int, ArrayValue VARCHAR(500))
INSERT INTO @tblWords (IDArray, ArrayValue) SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Split] (@Search, ' ')

SELECT IDArticle, ArticleText, COUNT(*) as [Result] FROM @tblWords
    JOIN Articles on ArticleText like ArrayValue + ' %' 
    OR ArticleText like '% ' + ArrayValue + '%' 
        GROUP BY IDArticle, ArticleText
        Order by Result desc
```

For those who want to try this, here's the table code:

```
CREATE TABLE [Articles] (
    [IDArticle] [int] IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL ,
    [ArticleText] [varchar] (500)
```

Thanks again Rusell, I owe you a coffee.